# Element-wise multiplication of an array and a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

How can I express multiplication of an array and a matrix so that

```
{x, y, z}*{{10, 20, 30}, {0, 1, 2}}
```

gives

```
{{10 x, 20 y, 30 z}, {0, y, 2 z}}
```

Comment: `{x, y, z}*# & /@ {{10, 20, 30}, {0, 1, 2}}`

Comment: A vectorized method is this: `{{10, 20, 30}, {0, 1, 2}}.DiagonalMatrix[{x, y, z}]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answers given in the comments to the question deserves being on record as a formal answer.

- Bob Hanlon

```
{x, y, z}*# & /@ {{10, 20, 30}, {0, 1, 2}}
```

- Henrik Schumacher

```
{{10, 20, 30}, {0, 1, 2}}.DiagonalMatrix[{x, y, z}]
```

- user1066

```
Inner[Times, {{10, 20, 30}, {0, 1, 2}}, {x,y,z}, List]
```

**EDIT:** Comparing the timings:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n = 20; r = 100;

var = Array[x, n];

mat = Array[m, {r, n}];

t[1] = AbsoluteTiming[prod[1] = var*# & /@ mat;][[1]]

(* 0.001768 *)

t[2] = AbsoluteTiming[prod[2] = mat.DiagonalMatrix[var];][[1]]

(* 0.027773 *)

t[3] = AbsoluteTiming[prod[3] = Inner[Times, mat, var, List];][[1]]

(* 0.001384 *)
```

Comparing the timings

```
(t /@ Range[3])/t[3]

(* {1.27746, 20.0672, 1.} *)
```

Verifying that the different approaches provide identical results.

```
Equal @@ (prod /@ Range[3])

(* True *)
```

Comment: Timing tests would be useful. If no one adds this before I have a chance, I will edit with them.

Comment: You might want to compare on packed arrays of reals as well, but you will need to repack the diagonal matrix before using Dot.

Comment: In addition  `{{10, 20, 30}, {0, 1, 2}}.DiagonalMatrix[{x,y,z}]==Inner[Times, {{10, 20, 30}, {0, 1, 2}}, {x,y,z}, List]==Inner[Times, {{10, 20, 30}, {0, 1, 2}}, DiagonalMatrix[{x,y,z}]]`  but timings may be  important

Comment: `m.DiagonalMatrix[v] == Inner[Times, m, DiagonalMatrix[v]] == Inner[Times, m, v, List]`,  where _m_ is matrix, _v_ is vector

Answer (score 1):

```
m = {{10, 20, 30}, {0, 1, 2}};

v = {x, y, z};
```

Using `Threaded` (new in 13.1}

```
m * Threaded[v]
```

{{10 x, 20 y, 30 z}, {0, y, 2 z}}

Answer (score 1):

```
m = {{10, 20, 30}, {0, 1, 2}};

v = {x, y, z};
```

Using `Cases`:

```
Cases[m, x_ :> x*v]

(*{{10 x, 20 y, 30 z}, {0, y, 2 z}}*)
```

Or using `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[#1*#2 &, {Array[v &, Length@#], #} &@m]

(*{{10 x, 20 y, 30 z}, {0, y, 2 z}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something as simple as this, which can be more efficient for large elements:

```
(a*{b, c}) /. {a -> {x, y, z}, b -> {10, 20, 30}, c -> {0, 1, 2}}

(* {{10 x, 20 y, 30 z}, {0, y, 2 z}} *)
```